# Watch PBS videos while in Spain using Proxy

Tags: proxy

First of all sorry if this was asked and answered already.

I am currently on a trip in Spain (but originally from USA), and would like to watch some PBS videos, but it tells me

> We're sorry, but this video is not available in your region due to
>   right restrictions.

OK, I get it, so let me tell PBS I am in their region by changing my Proxy!

I tried the: 
[FoxyProxy add on in Firefox with no success](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/foxyproxy-standard/).

My question is:

There is a setting in the System Preferances-Network-Advaced-Proxy!

I am not sure how to use it to get the [PBS to play the video](http://video.pbs.org/video/2365157997/).
I tried with a proxy from USA CA and still the same error message!

PS: yes, I did sign in in to PBS :(

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It appears that the PBS video is transported via `http`, but there are other resources on that page that connect via `https`. You may also need to establish an https proxy as well. In your screenshot, you only have an http proxy set up.